# Can we publish the customised changes in Microsoft BotFramework Webchat

Tags: c#, botframework, voice

I am actually building a bot using C#, but I need speech support in that, then came to know that we can customise the chat window using this repo. Though, I have no idea about nodejs, as mentioned in the steps to follow, I have installed npm and was able to enable the speech functionality by following these steps.

Build the project: "npm run build"
Start a web server: "npm run start"
Aim your browser at "http://localhost:8000/samples?[parameters as listed below]"
My query is whether we can publish and use the customised changes, or the above steps have to be done all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to build your own copy of Web Chat just to use speech.

Start with the [Speech Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/speech/index.html).

Then make the following two changes to reference the CDN copy of WebChat. By pointing to this, your website will always have the latest version.

Change [this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/speech/index.html#L24) to:

```
<link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And change [this line](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/speech/index.html#L56) to:

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
```